# Renew Apple Push Services on Firebase Cloud Messaging with p8 format

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

My Apple Push Services certificate is going to expire soon, so I created and downloaded a new one. Now I want to upload it on Firebase. There are two possibilities:

- Using a key (p8 format, recommended)
- Using a certificate (p12 format)

Our live app is currently using a key, so I'd like to do keep it this way.

The problem is, you can only create one key for Apple Push Services in Apple developer console. If I revoke the current one to create a new one, I've read it will immediately break the notifications for the live app.

The other thing I don't understand is that I'm not even sure I need to do this, since on different tutorials that explain how to create that key, it doesn't seem we are linking it to any certificate, like if that key never expires (but then why do I have some certificates that will expire?).

I'm kinda lost on what to do, can you help me?

Comment: Hello! Did you find the answer to your question? I'm in the same situation..

Answer (score 0):

Use a certificate (p12 format).

In Firebase: Project settings -> Cloud Messaging -> APNs Certificates -> Upload your P12 file